# SQL Server Installation Center - Feature selection - No Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssis

I need to run a SSIS package on a server, so I tried to install Integration services via SQL server installation center on the server. The SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2000.5) is updated from Express edition to Developer edition via SQL Server Installation Center.

When I try to install Integration services, Feature selection tab in installation center only shows a few features to select, and there is no Integration services (as shown in [image: Screenshot]).
Chosen database instance is developer edition (checked with select @@version), however in installation media folder, ENU folder is still called Express_ENU and not Developer_ENU, which is a bit confusing...
If anyone has an idea how this could be resolved, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to be wrong, but I think you'll be better served by uninstalling Express and doing a clean install of SQL Server 2019 developer edition.

Having Express and developer edition installed on the same machine is supported. I have developer edition for 2017 and 3 Express instances

[image]

But given what you're running into, I'd nuke the existing, install the full product and then if you need Express as well, install it again.